# error log bloated by add_view

Tags: errors

Has anyone else had any issues with their error log adding a line that just says add_view every few seconds?

e.g.

```
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:11 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:14 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:14 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:18 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:19 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:19 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:28 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:29 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:33 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:38 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:39 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:39 UTC] add_view
[03-Jun-2019 15:25:43 UTC] add_view
```

I can't work out what is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where this would be coming from, but it's likely a plugin or some custom code is doing this. You could try to track this down using `grep` on the command line:

```sh
cd /path/to/wp-content/
grep error_log -rn --include \*.php . | grep add_view
```

This should hopefully list any PHP files that have a line matching `error_log` and `add_view`.

Comment: Thanks, managed to track it down to the Author Stats Pro plugin, have disabled it for the time being and fired a support request back to the Author to get it fixed